# How to force a jquery mobile selectmenu to remain in the active state

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like my selectmenu to have the same behavior of a button. When I select an item in the list, the button remains "on". So I want my select menu to keep the ui-btn-active class after the click.

I tried this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".myselect", function() {
    if ( $(this).val() != "0" ) {
        $(this).closest("div").addClass("ui-btn-active");
    } else {
        $(this).closest("div").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
    }
});
```

It works for 1 second, but the class is removed just after. I suppose there is a refresh mechanism called after the click.

I suppose i should use a different event, but which one ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, `.selectmenu("refresh")` is called after `change` event to update virtual selectmenu. You could use `setTimeout()` to add `ui-btn-active` after 100ms or so.

Comment: It works, but every mouseover remove it immediately (of course). So I will use theme either.

Comment: A working example with theme : http://jsfiddle.net/3mRBZ/